# A python's beginner exercise

Tags: python

I work on "Think Python" and I'm having some trouble with this exercise:

> Python provides a built-in function called `len` that returns the length of a string, so the
>   value of `len('allen')` is `5`.
>   Write a function named `right_justify` that takes a string named `s` as a parameter and prints the
>   string with enough leading spaces so that the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly are you having trouble with? You need to be more specific, provide more detail, if you want help from us.

Comment: How about `right_justify = '{0:>70}'.format` ? (It's almost like writing a function)

Comment: One is normally expected to attempt to complete one's homework before posting it on StackOverflow ...

Comment: @holdenweb Actually,this isn't a homework.I'm trying to learn Python on my own

Comment: Sorry, I take that back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is to print space 70 times minus the length of your string, then your string.

```
print (' '*(70-len(s))+s)
```

Comment: While this is a correct answer, there's not much point giving the answers to problems like this. Better to give the algorithm at most, and let the OP work out the actual code.

Comment: Besides which there are easier ways, such as "%s70" % s or the formatting solution mentioned in the comments to the question.

Comment: Glad I could help, sorry if I was too direct in my response - Daniel et al have a point, it's better to work these things out yourself :) Good luck with the rest of the exercises!