# Python Exercise: Using repetition and concatenate

Tags: python

I am extremely new to Python and programming in general, and have been thinking about this supposedly simple exercise from a book called 'Think Python'and would like some help in understanding and solving this better. I apologize in advance if this is considered too 'simple' or off-topic, but I wasn't sure how to go about researching further about this specific example.

> **Write a function named right_justify that takes a string named s as a parameter and prints the string with enough leading spaces so that
>   the last letter of the string is in column 70 of the display.**
>
> right_justify('monty')
>
> Hint: Use string concatenation and repetition. Also, Python provides a
>   built-in function called len that returns the length of a string, so
>   the value of len('monty') is 5.

I have found an answer to this specific exercise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506998/a-pythons-beginner-exercise), but before I found that solution, I tried a solution of my own and would like to learn from solving it differently, even though it is much more long-winded.

At first, I thought it seemed simple; I just had to take the length of the parameter using the len function hinted, then divide 70 with that length and simply use string repetition with that division result to print. However, I quickly realized that this wouldn't work for arguments with a length where the division is not an integer but a floating number. So I came up with an idea:

```
    def right_justify(s):
        length = len(s)
        HP = int(70/length) 
#HP = Highest possible integer you can multiply with len(s) before exceeding total length of 70 , since int() will truncate a floating point result
        remainder = 70 - HP*length
        x = ' ', 'x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'x'*4, 'x'*5, 'x'*6, 'x'*7, 'x'*8, 'x'*9
        remainder = len(x)
        print(s*(HP-1)+x+s)
```

What I tried to do here was, first I filled up the entire row via repetition while leaving space for 1 last iteration of the input along with the remainder length if any. To make sure that the last letter is the last letter of the argument, I concatenate the remainder first to s*(HP-1), then join the last reiteration of s.

I already see problems with my code but I'm at a lost as to how to solve it. The first thing is the remainder: **How can I write the program such that x can have variable length, and I ensure that the x with the length equal to that of the remainder is always in the final print statement?**

Also, when I try to run the program, I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    right_justify('test')
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 8, in right_justify
    print(s*(HP-1)+x+s)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

I tried to Google the TypeError but the answers were too specific or advanced solutions such that I could not gain any understanding from them. I hope someone can help me understand the concepts involved in solving this problem and how to execute them. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Thank you for all the informative answers everyone! I appreciate all the different solutions given, there is a lot to learn from them. I decided to select Pepi's answer as he guided the way to solve this problem using tuples in my original train of thought.

Here is what I wrote using my newfound knowledge of tuples and index to solve this problem:

```
def right_justify(s):
        length = len(s)
        HP = int(70/length) 
#HP = Highest possible integer you can multiply with len(s) before exceeding total length of 70 , since int() will truncate a floating point result
        remainder = 70 - HP*length
        x = '', 'x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'x'*4, 'x'*5, 'x'*6, 'x'*7, 'x'*8, 'x'*9
        y = x[remainder]
        print(s*(HP-1)+y+s)
```

Thank you to Jack Taylor and Alain T. for the other very elegant solutions as well.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is actually a modulo operator you can use to find the remainder which is '%', so 8%3 would be 2 for example, because the remainder is 2. As for your error, notice that your 'x' variable is defined as a tuple of 10 different values, ' ' being the first and 'x'*9 being the last. You can't combine the string s with x since x isn't a string(and is a tuple instead). If you meant to get a particular value of x, you need to access it via indexing. Feel free to ask further questions if what I said was confusing :)

Comment: @Arch2K Thanks for the modulo operator tip, I didn't know that! I will read up more on indexing and tuples and how to connect these two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First -  the answer to your question:

The line

```
x = ' ', 'x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'x'*4, 'x'*5, 'x'*6, 'x'*7, 'x'*8, 'x'*9
```

creates a tuple, with is a kind of list, in this case contain the strings ' ', 'x', 'xx', 'xxx', ..., 'xxxxxxxxx'.

In order to concatenate one of these strings, get the one that you want using an index: x[i], where i is an integer from 0 to 9. (More generally, list types will be indexed from 0 to len(list)-1.)

```
x[2]  #returns 'xx'
```

The result of this reference will be str, and will concatenate to the rest of your string.

Lastly: I think you'll find shorter & clearer ways to solve the given problem, but there's nothing wrong with playing around for while. Hint: avoid floating point math here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! One question: is the ' ' in the tuple with nothing but a space not considered part of the list, since from your explanation you started the count in the list from 'x' as 0?

Comment: The ' ' is a part of the tuple. When I run `x[2]` with that tuple, I get "xx". I think writing "xxx" was a mistake on Pepi's part.

Comment: I fixed the answer to display "xx" instead of "xxx".

Comment: I also added the ' ' to the explanation of what the tuple holds.

Comment: @user21600 array/tuple indexing in most programming languages start from 0, so the first element actually has an index of 0. This is also why 'off by one' errors are actually surprisingly common

Answer (score 3):

If you're feeling lazy, you can use a [right-align format string](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align):

```
def right_justify(s):
    return "{:>70}".format(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

using concatenation, repetition and the len function:

```
" "*(70-len(s)) + s
```